# Markdown doesn't recognize URLs with non-ascii characters

Tags: bug, markdown, hyperlinks, url, unicode

I tried to link to the Wikipedia article on Möbius transformations, at `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Möbius_transformation`, using the markdown

```
[Möbius transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Möbius_transformation)
```

But Markdown didn't render the link properly. It looks like this:  Möbius transformations

I had to write the URL as `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%3Fbius_transformation` to get Markdown to generate a hyperlink.

I realize that Markdown needs to have some criterion for deciding where the URL ends, and that it needs to be fairly lax about this to avoid accidentally including the entire following text in the URL, but I think it should  at least understand that Unicode characters that have the “letter” property can be part of URLs. The `href` attribute in the rendered hyperlink could still be URL-encoded, for compatibility reasons.

Comment: A [related question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/520). And while I'm not denying that this could stand to be fixed, it's not the most critical thing because one can always URL-encode any special characters, as you did.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is strictly non-ascii characters.  I just had a similar problem [on this comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/743067/visually-deceptive-proofs-which-are-mathematically-wrong/743834?noredirect=1#comment1553124_743834)

Comment: @David I think the issue there is that you omitted the `http://`, so the text inside `(…)` did not look like a URL.